# How to handle this exception?

Tags: exception, haskell

Haskell is givinig me a headache today. I want to handle an exception. When it gets to the top it prints like this:

*** Exception: ../p/trip/Trip.hs:(88,16)-(89,50): Non-exhaustive patterns in function split

To me it looks like it is PatternMatchFail, but this doesn't work:

```
handle (\(PatternMatchFail _) -> return env) f
```

I mean, it compiles, but doesn't handle the exception. What am I doing wrong? Is this the wrong exception or what? Is there a way to catch any exception?

Comment: By the way, in the community this is an "error", not an exception.  It's an incorrect function, and the right answer is not to handle it, but to fix the function.  Of course, sometimes you can't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If fixing the source of the error is not an option, you should look at this:
http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Exception.html

I believe using "handle" or "try" or "catch" or whatever from Control.Exception is the key here, the functions in the standard prelude only deal with IO-Exceptions, not with errors in pure code.

In Haskell98, pure code cannot deal with exceptions. Pure functions must return a value, an exception is a failure to return a value.

Example:

```
import qualified Control.Exception as C
x ::String
x = undefined
y = "return value"

main = do C.handle (\_ -> return "caught") (C.evaluate x) >>= print
          C.handle (\_ -> return "caught") (C.evaluate y) >>= print
```

The call to evaluate is to force the evaluation of x and y, haskell being lazy and all.

If you let the evaluation of x be deferred until later (lazily), the exception will also be thrown later, in a different place (in this case it is "print" that uses the value), where it may not be caught.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. The computation was deferred and the exception was thrown later. Bitten by lazy evaluation yet one more time.

Comment: I am not getting this to work in GHC 7.0.3. "Ambiguous type variable `e1' in the constraint:
      (Exception e1) arising from a use of `handle'"

Comment: Sorry if the solution is obvious to other, using -XScopedTypeVariables
and explicitly typing the unused var in the lambda like: (\(_::C.SomeException) works as a fix. Is there a better method that I am missing though?